# Windows 7 vs Windows 10 Object cloning

Tags: windows, rpa, automationanywhere

I know that AAE 10.5 is not supported in Windows 10, just in Windows 7, and some of the features may not work properly. But I have a big problem with clicking one button. I have written a bot with 4 different options for clicking one (crucial) button on the web application.

So my attempts are below:
[image]

This one (MWC) works on Windows 10 but does not on windows 7.

[image]

This one also works on Windows 10 and does not on Windows 7
(I have tried both options for window and screen)

Btw. I know it's silly to use mouse clicks like that but I was desperate

And now what is interesting and very confusing for me:

[image]

Web recorder works only on Windows 7 but it has to be created on Windows 7, it doesn't work on Windows 7 if it's created on Windows 10.
On Windows 10 it is not working independently regardless whether it is created on Windows 10 or Windows 7.

[image]

..and saving the best for last: Object cloning prepared on Windows 10 is not working either on Windows 10 or Windows 7, however when prepared on Windows 7 works on Windows 7 and occasionally works on Windows 10.

Can someone explain what may be the reason and if there is any other way to click on the button on web application than those 4 mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

Quiet an interesting scenario, although for us we have most of the BOT runners on Win7.

I would consider going for Object cloning command because it recognizes the object characteristics rather than co-ordinates like in the case of Mouse clicks.

Here is my take on the situation:

- Object cloning for **AAE Client(10.5)** works well if your BotCreator and Bot Runner is on Windows 7.
- Windows 10 is not recommended O.S for AAE Client 10.5, although there is a slight mismatch noticed in during object clonings radar-locking system, as a work around I have tried lowering the resolution which gave me good results.

> Can someone explain what may be the reason and if there is any other way to click on button on web application than those 4 mentioned above.

- Irrespective of the O.S, Object cloning works best on an I.E with zoom 100%
- You can also try and navigate to the button using keystrokes ( Try to find the tab cycle)
- Use Image recognition along side error handling to click on a button when present

Comment: Biggest problem is that I am using windows 10 and I cannot downgrade it, while server, control room works on windows 7. 
I have checked my zoom in IE and it's same 100%, 
Value that I want to click and I have not mentioned it is in drop-down menu, where I cannot use keystrokes like tab or arrows. Image recognition doesn't work aswell probably due to fact that wanted value is placed in different places of drop-down menu depends on type of case.

Comment: In object cloning, there is a property that fetches child items, you can try exploring.
Even if it is in drop down menu you get the dropdown arrow and click enter which opens the list and so forth.

Comment: @Piotr if the menu option you are looking for moves then object cloning using domxpath and path will not work consistently as they rely on the position of the element not changing. If the element has a unique ID you can try using that as one of the search properties. Otherwise just remove the domxpath and path selectors. But be careful if you are just using tag=A and HTML inner text=Release PO if there is another link on screen which matches this criteria it will attempt to use this tag as well.

Comment: Hi Alan, yes that was one of my ideas, and now also it become a good practice to avoid criteria of DomxPath and Path. As I realize after each update, change in the app the paths changes so it's very change sensitive. But despite that object cloning does want to work on some apps on windows 7, if it's created on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

So that's not perfect and seems pretty like a big walk round solution, but what I have done to make this code run. I have to put if statement that checks the windows version and according to result it runs different method to handle drop-down menu:

[image]

Object cloning was made on different computer with windows 7.
I have run this code on two computers with windows 7 and only one with windows 10, but it worked properly. After all cause I do not have access to another computer with windows 10 for now I cannot say 100% that's windows 10/7 thing but it's my main suspect(windows version).